# simulate driving a route in device -iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, location

I have a location based app that provides information for a driving trip in real time. I would like to test that app in device. How can I mock an entire trip without actually driving. I see a solution exists for Android through mock location apps, is there anything similar for iPhone as well? I would appreciate any pointer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you can create a GPX file and load it in XCode.

When you start debugging an app in xcode on the bottom where the debugging logging is there is the breakpoint |> and || and there you will see a location icon (see image, black icon all the way to the right). Click that and it will give you option to add GPX file. Generate a GPX file of the route you want and when you load it the phone / simulator will automatically go through those points  [image: Arrow all the way to right]

Comment: Thanks adrian. Is it possible to pass GPX file to app without going through XCode?

Comment: You would have to build a gpx parser or something and set location to that. You have to do that all yourself. This way mentioned above emulates the gps radio.